# Fetching and parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, decodable

I’m having a really hard time fetching and parsing the following JSON. I can't even fetch the data from given url, even less parse it using my data Model "Car". Any help is more than welcomed!

JSON

```
{
   "cars":[
      {
         "date_stolen":1604616183,
         "description":null,
         "body_colors":[
            "Black",
            "Blue"
         ],
         "id":"944846",
         "is_stock_img":false,
         "large_img":null,
         "location_found":null,
         "manufacturer_name":"Toyota",
         "external_id":null,
         "registry_name":null,
         "registry_url":null,
         "serial":"36-17-01012-xl09",
         "status":null,
         "stolen":true,
         "stolen_location":"Calgary - CA",
         "thumb":null,
         "title":"2017 Toyota Corolla ",
         "url":"https://cars.org/944846",
         "year":2017
      }
   ]
}
```

```
struct Car: Decodable {
        let cars: String
    }
```

```
var cars = [Car]()
```

```
fileprivate func fetchJSON() {
        let urlString = "someUrl…"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let data = data else { return }
                
                do {
                    
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                    print("DATA \n", data)
                    self.cars = try decoder.decode(Car.self, from: data)
                    
                    print("---> ", data)
                    
                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Failed to decode:", jsonErr)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: What's the outputs?

Comment: Your data model car does not reflect the json structure.

Comment: Since `cars` is not a string, it won't parse

Comment: Your JSON is not well formed. It has mismatched quotes, mismatched "[" and mismatched "{" characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Car model does not represent you json structure.

You're looking for something like this :

```
struct CarsResponse: Decodable {
    let cars: [CarDTO]
}

struct CarDTO: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let isStockImg: Bool
    // And so on
}
```

Then just write :

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let carResponse = try decoder.decode(CarsResponse.self, from: data)
```

You will access your cars by writing

```
let cars: [CarDTO] = carResponse.cars
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This seems to work. I had to replace "self.cars = try decoder.decode(Car.self, from: data)" with "let data = try decoder.decode(Car.self, from: data)" because of type mismatch. Need to figure out how to extract the response now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the Codable Protocol and `JSONDecoder()` you will need to create a Struct that matches the format of your JSON. As others have pointed out in their comments, your Car struct is completely different than the format of the data you are receiving.

If you just want to deserialize the JSON you are receiving into dictionaries containing values, you could instead use JSONSerialization.

To do that you could replace the body of your `do` block with code like this:

```
let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
```

You'd then have to navigate the dictionary structure of `object` yourself. It isn't as clean as creating a custom struct and using Codable, but it works.

Note that your JSON has syntax errors in it. Here is a cleaned-up version:

```
{"cars":
    [
        {"date_stolen":1604616183,
            "description":null,
            "body_colors":["Black","Blue"],
            "id":944846,
            "is_stock_img":false,
            "large_img":null,
            "location_found":null,
            "manufacturer_name":"Toyota",
            "external_id":null,
            "registry_name":null,
            "registry_url":null,
            "serial":"36-17-01012-xl09",
            "status":null,
            "stolen":true,
            "stolen_location":"Calgary - CA",
            "thumb":null,
            "title":"2017 Toyota Corolla ",
            "url":"https://cars.org/944846",
            "year":2017
        }
    ]
}
```

(I added whitespace for readability. It doesn't affect the parsing one way or the other.)